# execute powershell script stored in sql server table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

Is there any way we can run a powershell script stored inside a sql server table from a Sql Server stored procedure?

Comment: Could you please ask your question again in clear words `"is a way we can run the powershell script from the sql server table"` what does this mean ? Also in the end you have mentioned stored procedures `"Is it possible to execute it from sql stored procedure ?"`, your question does not make any sense at all.

Comment: No you can't run powershell from inside a SQL Stored procedure. You can from a SQL Agent job though and you can create and execute those from TSQL. This is not a nice solution though...

Comment: @MartinSmith not even with `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: Executing arbitrary code on the host system with elevated permissions seems a bit risky to me. How are you controlling and validating the script code that's on your table?

Comment: @alroc forgot about that

Answer (score 2):

There's the built-in sproc [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql) that can be used to do some...extremely hacky things.  It can not only be used to issue command-line statements from within T-SQL, but also be used in conjunction with `bcp` to save the results of a select query to a file, [as described in this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/).

So yes, what you're asking is theoretically possible.  You can construct a T-SQL statement to save the powershell script to a file, then call xp_cmdshell a second time to execute the file you've just saved.  (Caveat:  I've successfully done each of these individually for a couple of projects, but never combined the two.  Your mileage may vary.)

Whether you should actually do this, though, is another matter.  There are two things to consider:

1. Most developers will consider the use of this (admittedly rather convoluted) logic within a stored procedure a nasty hack, as it is difficult to debug/maintain.  How does the caller determine if the script completed or not?  How does the caller track that the command was correctly issued at all?  How does the next developer maintain this when things are breaking?
2. There are security considerations as well.  Obviously the file will only be saved, and its script will only execute, if the xp_cmdshell calls are issued by a user with enough rights to do so.  Opening these rights up could potentially open some security holes....and resolving issues with rights not being adequate could be equally challenging.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was pretty old, but the MS docs (from the link) state 'applies to 2008'.  Probably some text within the article and not the command itself.  I'll edit my response.

Comment: Yep the online help doesn't go back before that. As you will see in `SELECT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql